# How to increase the paper size as per my image size using FPDF-php?

Tags: php, fpdf

When I tried inserting an image with PHP and FPDF, the image is not shown in PDF as the original.

I have got fPDF from this [link](https://ishakali.wordpress.com/2013/09/20/convert-image-into-pdf-using-php/)

Used the below code from the above link

```
require('lib/fpdf.php');
        $image = MEDIA_DIR."uploads/".$report_img.".png";
        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->Image($image,10,10,200,500);
        $pdf->Output();
```

I was not able to load 1000px*10000px size image as it is, it shows as compressed.

How to increase the paper size as per my image size?

Comment: do you have a question? because what you have its a statement

Comment: There's nothing updated here!! where is your code?

Comment: Added the code now.

Comment: are u adding the image on the header? or in the body cells of your fpdf?

Comment: In my PDF Body .............

Comment: How about redim your image first?

Comment: If I do resize, quality is going down.

Comment: Try to put the image inside a cell then control cell dimensions `$pdf->cell(1000, 1000, $pdf->Image('http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World',10,10,200,500,'PNG'));`

Comment: can u attach your image on your question as well

Comment: Attached the image.

Comment: ok, thats the image you wanna add on your PDF?

Comment: well, Its loading on my side, you just need to create a cell for the image then have the image inside the cell

Comment: Can you update my code and comment here. `FPDF error: No font has been set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it by adding my image into a cell like below

```
require('lib/fpdf.php');
        $image = MEDIA_DIR."uploads/pdf_images/".$report_img.".png";
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($image);
        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->SetSize(($width/2)+110,($height*57/100)); //Custom function
        $pdf->AddPage('','custom');
        $pdf->cell(1000,1000,'',$pdf->Image($image,10,10,235,$height*18/100),'PNG');
        $pdf->Output();
```

Add the below function to fpdf.php

```
function SetSize($width,$height)
{
    $this->StdPageSizes['custom']=array($width,$height);
}
```