# Auto sized the cell width with text width using FPDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf

I am beginning to use the `FPDF` to export the pdf from the Mysql. Now that i can export the pdf. I have referenced [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981530/how-to-auto-resize-the-cell-in-fpdf-using-php) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972271/show-a-link-in-fpdf), but I still cannot change the cell width and text width.
Could anyone provide any suggestions? Thank you very much.

```
<?php
require('mysql_table.php');

class PDF extends PDF_MySQL_Table
{
function Header()
{
//Title
$this->SetFont('Arial','',18);
$this->Cell(0,6,'Test',0,1,'C');
$this->Ln(10);
//Ensure table header is output
parent::Header();
}
}

mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('test');
$query = "SELECT * FROM test";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$rowCount = 2;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$thisid = $row['ID'];
$fileName =$row['name'];
$filepath = $row['path'];
$date = $row['date'];
$rowCount++;
}
$pdf=new PDF('P','mm',array(1000,1500));
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Table('select * from test');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
$pdf->Cell('','',$thisid,1);
$pdf->Cell('','',$fileName,1);
$pdf->Cell('','','','','','',false,$filepath);
$pdf->Cell('','',$date);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below answer to set cell width
[Inserting an image with PHP and FPDF, failed to load big image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650298/inserting-an-image-with-php-and-fpdf-failed-to-load-big-image)

As per your question you may need to pass width and height like below to `cell()` function

```
$pdf->cell(1000,1000,'',$pdf->Image($image,10,10,235,$height*18/100),'PNG');
```

This is to resize the cell and load img into the same

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to solve this problem... here the concept is only if string size greater than your cell width then font size will reduce.

**Note that you can not use this code for a multi-line string. for this, you have to use MultiCell()**

```
$table_head1=array(25,46,40,20,60);
$table_head2=array(25,20,26,20,20,16,24,40);
// some code remove from here for show actual code.
$pdf->CellFit($table_head2[7],$table_height,$item['remark'],1,0,'C',0,'',1,0);
```

use this link

[how to auto adjust cell width in fpdf using php and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603371/how-to-auto-adjust-cell-width-in-fpdf-using-php-and-mysql)